# username:password@localhost URL with Undertow

Tags: java, servlets, undertow

Is there any way to access to username/password URL parts using Undertow server? It it possible with any other java-based HTTP server?

Comment: Say what do you want?

Comment: @Antoniossss i need to parse login and password from request URL, but Undertow's HttpServerExchange object does not contain this info. Undertow returns request URL like 'http://locahost' removing authority part

Comment: that is because browsers translate the syntax to basic auth. You should find a header like `Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=`, which when decoded with base64 results in plaintext `username:password`

Comment: @zapl Thanks a lot!